# Real time chat using laravel & redis

Tags: node.js, laravel, redis, chat, real-time

I just follow the steps shown in this link http://itsolutionstuff.com/post/laravel-52-chat-message-module-using-socketio-redis-express-and-nodejs-from-from-scratchexample.html to creat a real time chat it works perfictly , but this way it sends messages to all users, I want chat to be one to one. 
any suggestions ?

Comment: This will guve you an idea: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9137877/socket-io-send-to-specified-user-id

Comment: Thanks I will try it.

Answer (score 0):

I'm sorry, but i think you should be more specific.

I can't give you the right recipe for a good solution, 
but i think you're choosing the wrong platforms to make 
a messenger-chat.

Try look at NodeJS and maybe use Socket.io to communicate through.

[Socket.io](http://socket.io/) has an example on how to make a [simple chat](http://socket.io/demos/chat/). You can use the example
as a starting point for your project.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, redis and node js are wrong platforms ? can you explain why ?

Comment: can you describe how this stuff should be done ? I'm confusing ?